# Is it possible in Windows 7 64 bit to use 64 bit com dlls (in process servers) from a 32 bit exe application?

Tags: 32bit-64bit

Is it possible in Windows 7 64 bit to use 64 bit com dlls (in process servers) from a 32 bit exe application?

I need to leave my VB6 gui application as 32 bit running on a windows 7 system but it has calls to com dlls (in process servers) and com exe's ( out of process servers).

My understanding is that it should have no problem with the com exe's the out of process servers.

I think the com dll in process server may have trouble since it is 64 bit but the application calling it is 32 bit.

Has anyone used a 64 bit com dll from a 32 bit application?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A solution to this is discussed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8484244/147637  (Read the whole post)

Answer (score 0):

Years ago I used a 32bit DLL in a 16bit app.  I don't remember how we did it (and the technique would surely not still be applicable), but this is generally called "thunking".

A quick Google would appear to indicate this can't be done in process, but I only scanned:
http://www.google.com/search?q=thunking+64bit+32bit+dll

Comment: I was really wondering if a COM dll which has an ipc interface layer could get around the issues stated in your links for regular dll's.