# Firebird fbclient.dll and gds32.dll bitness for 64-bit program?

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, firebird, delphi-11-alexandria

When converting my 32-bits Delphi Alexandria 11.3 program from 32-bit to 64-bit, I noticed that the directory with the executable also contains Firebird's `fbclient.dll` which is identical to the file in `c:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_3_0\WOW64\`

The Firebird version is 3.0 64-bit (installer `Firebird-3.0.4.33054_0_x64.exe`)

- SysInternals
  [sigcheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck)
  reports that fbclient.dll as 32-bit.
- The [trick of inspecting the DLL with an editor](https://www.greytrix.com/blogs/sageaccpacerp/2022/01/18/how-to-check-dll-is-32-bit-or-64-bit/) also shows a 32-bit file.
- Someone in thread
  https://firebird-support.yahoogroups.narkive.com/xbq3IDed/unable-to-load-64bit-fbclient-dll however, says that it is a 64-bit version.

Given that it is practically [required to use 64-bit DLLs from a 64-bit program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484204/how-can-i-call-a-32-bit-dll-from-64-bit-code) it seems that I do not have a 64-bit `fbclient.dll` anywhere?

During Firebird installation we checked the option to create `gds32.dll` in the Windows system directory, i.e. a copy of `fbclient.dll` was renamed to act as the Interbase client library `gds32.dll` ([source](https://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=25839)).

To make matters worse, according to sigcheck, the two `gds32.dll` versions in `C:\Windows\System32` and `C:\Windows\SysWow64` are 64- and 32-bit respectively.

[image]

What's the deal here?

Do I have to dig up 64-bit `fbclient.dll` somewhere?

Why the weird bitness reported for both copies of `gds32.dll`? Am I misunderstanding the function of SysWow64 here?

I already tried a reinstall of Firebird over the current installation (so not a complete removal/reinstall yet)

Comment: Delphi is a 32 bit program. The 32bit dll's need to be in the Embarcadero\bin folder if you want to open connections and queries at design time. We avoid putting the dll's in the \Windows folders, and instead place them in the same folder as the exe. Try it.

Comment: It may look a bit strange, but Microsoft named the folder with the 64-bit dlls _system32_, while the one for the 32-bit DLLs is named _syswow64_.

Comment: That's because WOW64 means "**W**indows(32) **o**n **W**indows **64**" and `System32` is just the _core_ which got its name from advancing from [`System` in the non-NT era](https://www.cs.oberlin.edu/~rms/mmcc/a/mod6/mod6411.html?c47) to NT.

Comment: What make things even trickier, System32 folder is virtual and is swapped with SysWow64 depending on  bitness of the application that read it.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to Interbase, the Firebird clients are consistently named *fbclient.dll*. In a 64-Bit installation of Firebird server the *bin* folder contains the 64-bit version of fbclient.dll, while the 32-bit version resides in the *WOW64* folder.

While there are reasons to rename a fbclient.dll to gds32.dll to keep old (BDE) software happy, it should be done only when really necessary. Doing this will make it pretty hard to have InterBase and Firebird installed on the same machine, which in my experience turned out to be pretty common these days.

FireDAC requires fbclient.dll only and doesn't fall back to gds32.dll, so there is no need for the renaming.

Comment: Simple rename can bite since Firebird 3. "instclient i g" not only copy library but also does a couple of binary hacks on it.

Comment: Since Firebird 3.0, the layout of Firebird installations on Windows no longer have a `bin` directory. The executables and DLLs are in the main installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 64-bit, the `System32` folder contains **64-bit** DLLs, and the `SysWOW64` contains the 32-bit DLLs. Microsoft is historically bad at naming things...

The `gds32.dll` is something that the Firebird installer (or its `instclient` tool) can still generate for tools still expecting the old names from InterBase times. The 64-bit variant is also called `gds32.dll`, but the main library you should be using is `fbclient.dll` (the `gds32.dll` is either a copy of `fbclient.dll` or a shim redirecting calls to `fbclient.dll`).

If you configured the Firebird installer to install client libraries, it will have installed the 64-bit DLL(s) in `%WINDIR%\System32` and the 32-bit DLL(s) in `%WINDIR%\SysWOW64`. You should find the `fbclient.dll` libraries there, unless you explicitly unchecked the *"Copy Firebird client library to <system> directory?"* option, but did check the *"Generate client library as GDS32.DLL for legacy InterBase support?"*.

In addition, the installation directory of Firebird (default `C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_4_0`) itself contains a 64-bit `fbclient.dll` in the main installation directory, and a 32-bit variant in its `WOW64` directory.